# Expression tree is not printing what it should

Tags: java, tree, expression-trees

I'm coding an expression tree for school but it is not printing what it should. Can someone help me?

```java
package proyecto.pkg3;

import java.util.Stack;

public class ExpressionTree {
    private ExpressionNode root;

    public ExpressionTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public void buildTree(String expression) {
        Stack<ExpressionNode> stack = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
            char character = expression.charAt(i);

            if (character == ' ') {
                continue;
            }

            if (character == '(') {
                stack.push(new ExpressionNode(character));
            } else if (character == ')') {
                ExpressionNode operator = stack.pop();
                ExpressionNode rightNode = stack.pop();
                ExpressionNode leftNode = stack.pop();
                operator.left = leftNode;
                operator.right = rightNode;
                stack.push(operator);
            } else if (isOperator(character)) {
                stack.push(new ExpressionNode(character));
            } else {
                StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
                while (i < expression.length() && Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(i))) {
                    number.append(expression.charAt(i));
                    i++;
                }
                i--;

                int value = Integer.parseInt(number.toString());
                stack.push(new ExpressionNode((char) (value + '0'))); 
            }
        }

        root = stack.isEmpty() ? null : stack.pop();
    }

    private boolean isOperator(char c) {
        return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/';
    }

    private int evaluate(ExpressionNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            return node.value - '0';
        }

        int left = evaluate(node.left);
        int right = evaluate(node.right);

        return switch (node.value) {
            case '+' ->
                left + right;
            case '-' ->
                left - right;
            case '*' ->
                left * right;
            case '/' ->
                left / right;
            default ->
                0;
        };
    }

    public void printTree() {
        recursivePrintTree(root);
    }

    private void recursivePrintTree(ExpressionNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            recursivePrintTree(node.right);
            System.out.print(node.value + " ");
            recursivePrintTree(node.left);
        }
    }

    public int solve() {
        return evaluate(root);
    }
}
```

The program must receive a string like this: `(3+10)*(5)`, this should print 65 but prints 0 and when printing the tree prints " * 5 ( ".

Comment: For your example at the end of the question, what should the expression tree look like instead of `" * 5 ( "`.

Comment: `new ExpressionNode((char) (value + '0')));` this seems pretty questionable.  If you have an integer you add `'0'` to it?  You realize that this won't work for number greater than 9, or less than 0?  And that some number greater than 9 will actually be symbols like '*' and '+' because those characters come after the numbers?

Comment: For example, 10 + '0' is equal to `':'`. (That's a colon.)  Are you sure that's what you want?